# How to change color of a button in ion-item-sliding in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to have a red button in an ion-item-sliding element in Ionic 4. Here is the code:

```
  <ion-card>
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="assets/shapes.svg">
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-label>
        <h3>test</h3>
        <p>test</p>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
          <button ion-button color="danger">
            <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
            Delete
          </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-card>
```

However, the button shows in gray while it should be red. I also tried using ion-button instead of button. It worked, but when I coupled it with `expand="full"` the color of button's text turned red instead of the color of button itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the defaut button is working fine:

```
<ion-card>
<ion-item-sliding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
      <img src="assets/shapes.svg">
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="end">
    <ion-item-option color="danger" expandable>
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
    </ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

[image]

Hope it helps you :)